# Javascript only works once?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I don't know why, but my Javascript only works once in Firefox and IE (but it works fine in Chrome). Does anybody know why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeDivImage() 
       { 
        var imgPath = new String(); 
        imgPath = document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage; 
        if (imgPath == "url(images/1.jpg)" || imgPath == "")
          { 
           document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage ="url(images/2.jpg)"; 
          } 
        else if (imgPath == "url(images/2.jpg)")
          { 
           document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/3.jpg)"; 
          }
        else if (imgPath == "url(images/3.jpg)")
          { 
           document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundImage = "url(images/1.jpg)"; 
          }  
       }   
  </script>
```

Script is triggered by clicking on image

```
<img src="images/leftarrow.png"
     value="Change Background Image"
     onclick="changeDivImage()" />
```

Comment: Check what the value of `imgPath` is after changing background once.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Have you stepped through with a debugger to see if the if conditions are evaluating as you expected?

Comment: `new String()`? Really? You do realise that you're immediately throwing that object away by assigning a value to the same variable, right?

Comment: yeah, unless it's Java (not JavaScript), there's no need to declare the variable as a `new String()`

Answer (score 1):

Browsers tend to normalise CSS properties in different ways. IE and Firefox put quotes around the URL, for instance.

So, perhaps you should try this instead:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div1'),
    imgPath = parseInt(div.style.backgroundImage.match(/\d(?=\.jpg)/) || ["0"],10),
    newnum = imgPath%3+1;
div.style.backgroundImage = "url(images/"+newnum+".jpg)";
```

Comment: or start using jQuery and use `.attr("src")`.. and voila!

Comment: @Tom: ... seriously? If that's a serious answer, then I hate you.

Comment: not so serious answer, no.. but do you really despise jQuery so much that you'ld HATE me? What do you really have against it?

Comment: Nothing against jQuery itself, just that people horrendously abuse it. Why would you have the browser go through a million steps just to get an attribute that can be fetched in one call?